# Handling missing Tags in 'aws | jq' command (jq: error Cannot iterate over null)

Tags: jq, aws-cli

I'm trying to write a simple script to output a table of AWS EC2 instance information (instance-id, ip, name) using 'jq'.

However, in our environment, some instances do not have any tags associated with them, so when I run my script I get an error, at which point jq stops processing before iterating over the remainding elements of the array:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances | \
  jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | (.Tags | from_entries) as $tags | "\(.InstanceId)  \(.PrivateIpAddress)  \($tags.Name)"'

i-0664dc6c236767b4e  10.177.99.141  foo
i-02077630c093d65dc  10.177.99.85  bar
jq: error (at <stdin>:2108): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Is there a way I can filter for non-existent Tags and substitute a placeholder value for Name (like '-'), to avoid this error and produce a clean output?

Answer (score 2):

To ignore those instances, you could use `.Tags // empty`, like so:

```
jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[]
  | ((.Tags // empty) | from_entries) as $tags
  | "\(.InstanceId)  \(.PrivateIpAddress)  \($tags.Name)"'
```

One way to add placeholder values would be to use an `if ... then ... else ... end` construction, e.g.

```
jq -r '
.Reservations[].Instances[]
  | (if .Tags then (.Tags | from_entries).Name else "-" end) as $name
  | "\(.InstanceId)  \(.PrivateIpAddress)  \($name)"'
```

If you need further details, then please follow the
[minimal complete verifiable example guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).